# Embedding CSS and JS files into HTML with GruntJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs

At present I am using static HTML pages for a project I am working on and they all require the same CSS and JS files. Now instead of copying the scripts, I would like to insert all of the tags with GruntJS.

For example, if we have 'css/style.css', then insert

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

However it should not be hardcoded, thus it should insert the actual filename and path. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I think there is no way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

First, set-up contrib-copy with content processing using grunt-template:

```
  grunt.config('copy', {
    options: {
      processContent: function (content, srcpath) {
        return grunt.template.process(content);
      }
    }
  });
```

Now, whenever you copy your html files to their destination, any grunt template marker will be replaced by the appropriate value.

Say you have an html file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <%= something %>
    </head>
</html>
```

All you would need then would be, somewhere in your config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  something: "<doh></doh>"
});
```

Now, the content of "something" should probably come from the result of another task (a task that would copy all your css / js files) - that shouldn't be too hard to do.

You should probably play a bit first, read the docs, and do some tests with grunt-template, grunt-contrib-copy, and creating custom grunt tasks - then ask for a more specific question.

http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy

http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template

Hope that helps.